# newbie simple layout for vertical alignment in containing box

Tags: html, css

Need to vertically align images within a containing box like this:

```
   <span class="image-box"><img src="/1_thumb.jpg"></span>
```

with this:

```
.image-box{
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  // ????
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

The vertical-align is not working correcty. How would I align this?

thx

Comment: How are you trying to vertically align them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign this CSS to the image `vertical-align: middle;` and add this line of CSS to the `.image-box` `line-height: 75px;`. The value for `height` and `line-height` should be the same.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/SjKUa/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add this and maybe change the 0 to however much space you would want between the images. This will line them up centered inside of your column which is what it seems like you are after.

```
 .image-box img {
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```